# Create a new start date and end date based on the sequence position number,

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, date, gaps-and-islands

How to create a new start date and end date based on the sequence position number:

From

```
EmpNo   StartDate   EndDate     PositionNumber
832319  4/05/2020   10/05/2020  32681
832319  11/05/2020  17/05/2020  32681
832319  18/05/2020  24/05/2020  32681
832319  25/05/2020  31/05/2020  32681
832319  1/06/2020   7/06/2020   32681
832319  8/06/2020   14/06/2020  32681
832319  15/06/2020  21/06/2020  32783
832319  22/06/2020  28/06/2020  32783
832319  29/06/2020  5/07/2020   32783
832319  6/07/2020   12/07/2020  32781
832319  13/07/2020  19/07/2020  32781
832319  20/07/2020  26/07/2020  32681
832319  27/07/2020  2/08/2020   32681
```

To (create two new field for new start date and new end date)

```
EmpNo   StartDate   EndDate     PositionNumber  NewStartDate    New EndDate
832319  4/05/2020   10/05/2020  32681   4/05/2020   14/06/2020
832319  11/05/2020  17/05/2020  32681   4/05/2020   14/06/2020
832319  18/05/2020  24/05/2020  32681   4/05/2020   14/06/2020
832319  25/05/2020  31/05/2020  32681   4/05/2020   14/06/2020
832319  1/06/2020   7/06/2020   32681   4/05/2020   14/06/2020
832319  8/06/2020   14/06/2020  32681   4/05/2020   14/06/2020
832319  15/06/2020  21/06/2020  32783   21/06/2020  5/07/2020
832319  22/06/2020  28/06/2020  32783   21/06/2020  5/07/2020
832319  29/06/2020  5/07/2020   32783   21/06/2020  5/07/2020
832319  6/07/2020   12/07/2020  32781   6/07/2020   19/07/2020
832319  13/07/2020  19/07/2020  32781   6/07/2020   19/07/2020
832319  20/07/2020  26/07/2020  32681   20/07/2020  2/08/2020
832319  27/07/2020  2/08/2020   32681   20/07/2020  2/08/2020
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: What have you tried? Where did you get stuck?

Answer (score 1):

I understand this as a gaps-and-island problem. You want to the minimum and maximum date of "adjacent" rows sharing the same `empNo` and `positionNo`.

Here is an approach using window functions. The idea is to use `lag()` and a cumulative `sum()` to define the groups:

```
select 
    empNo,
    startDate,
    endDate,
    positionNumber,
    min(startDate) over(partition by empNo, positionNumber, grp) newStartDate,
    max(endDate)   over(partition by empNo, positionNumber, grp) newEndDate
from (
    select 
        t.*,
        sum(case when startDate = dateadd(day, 1, lagEndDate) then 0 else 1 end)
            over(partition by empNo, positionNumber order by endDate) grp
    from (
        select 
            t.*, 
            lag(endDate) 
                over(partition by empNo, positionNumber order by endDate) lagEndDate
        from mytable t
    ) t
) t
order by empNo, startDate
```

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=3438d1093fbcf8e1f9b7ba1c71750595)**:

```
 empNo | startDate  | endDate    | positionNumber | newStartDate | newEndDate
-----: | :--------- | :--------- | -------------: | :----------- | :---------
832319 | 2020-05-04 | 2020-05-10 |          32681 | 2020-05-04   | 2020-06-14
832319 | 2020-05-11 | 2020-05-17 |          32681 | 2020-05-04   | 2020-06-14
832319 | 2020-05-18 | 2020-05-24 |          32681 | 2020-05-04   | 2020-06-14
832319 | 2020-05-25 | 2020-05-31 |          32681 | 2020-05-04   | 2020-06-14
832319 | 2020-06-01 | 2020-06-07 |          32681 | 2020-05-04   | 2020-06-14
832319 | 2020-06-08 | 2020-06-14 |          32681 | 2020-05-04   | 2020-06-14
832319 | 2020-06-15 | 2020-06-21 |          32783 | 2020-06-15   | 2020-07-05
832319 | 2020-06-22 | 2020-06-28 |          32783 | 2020-06-15   | 2020-07-05
832319 | 2020-06-29 | 2020-07-05 |          32783 | 2020-06-15   | 2020-07-05
832319 | 2020-07-06 | 2020-07-12 |          32781 | 2020-07-06   | 2020-07-19
832319 | 2020-07-13 | 2020-07-19 |          32781 | 2020-07-06   | 2020-07-19
832319 | 2020-07-20 | 2020-07-26 |          32681 | 2020-07-20   | 2020-07-26
832319 | 2020-07-27 | 2020-02-08 |          32681 | 2020-07-27   | 2020-02-08
```

Comment: Thank you so much, this is what I would like to archive. But, is there other options than using LAG as I am on SQL 2005.

Comment: @serenityendy: solving this problem without window functions is highly challenging. You should really consider upgrading: SQL 2005 is unsupported software.

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for the minimum start date and maximum end date?

```
select t.*,
       min(startdate) over (partition by empno, positionnumber) as new_startdate,
       min(enddate) over (partition by empno, positionnumber) as new_enddate
from t
```